# Why does Jesus' Resurrection mean hope for an individual and in what context?

Tags: afterlife, resurrection-of-jesus, easter

This Easter, the phrase "Jesus' Resurrection represents hope for you and your family", was repeatedly stated among different Christian outlets (sermons, radio stations, banners, etc nation wide in the U.S.).

However, not much of an explanation why.

In this question: [Why the resurrection?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9278/why-the-resurrection)
the Resurrection does not really focus on hope for individuals but more about the ***hope that Jesus is really God and as a way to heaven***.

However, I also found this quote:

> "knowing that he which raised up the Lord Jesus shall raise up us
>   also by Jesus."--2 Corinthians 4:14

So does this hope pertain to an individuals every day life experience here on earth.... or is it a more spiritual hope in Jesus and heaven?

http://newsinfo.inquirer.net/595852/tagle-christs-resurrection-a-message-of-hope-to-faithful

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer what the particular ad meant by it.

Comment: @david-brainerd: "particular ad"? No, much more than that...this is the means by which many people come to Christ..through their brokenness and a hope for repair

Comment: I think, simply put, it's a hope that Jesus wasn't the only one that will be raised from death to life eternal. A hope that we won't just fall asleep forever... Yet that is appealing for some, I believe. For me... I am uncertain that I would even want to "live" forever. Resting In Peace may be better... I do not now. And that bothers me... That's why I'm here anyways.

Answer (score 3):

The hope we have in Jesus's resurrection is that He died for our sins, and He rose from the grave.  We can go to Heaven because of this.  Without Jesus, we would remain condemned in our sins.  Romans explains in detail:

> [Rom 6:9-23 NKJV] ... knowing that Christ, having been raised from the dead, dies no more. Death no longer has dominion over Him.  For [the death] that He died, He died to sin once for all; but [the life] that He lives, He lives to God.  Likewise you also, reckon yourselves to be dead indeed to sin, but alive to God in Christ Jesus our Lord.  Therefore do not let sin reign in your mortal body, that you should obey it in its lusts.  And do not present your members [as] instruments of unrighteousness to sin, but present yourselves to God as being alive from the dead, and your members [as] instruments of righteousness to God.  For sin shall not have dominion over you, for you are not under law but under grace.  What then? Shall we sin because we are not under law but under grace? Certainly not! Do you not know that to whom you present yourselves slaves to obey, you are that one's slaves whom you obey, whether of sin [leading] to death, or of obedience [leading] to righteousness?  But God be thanked that [though] you were slaves of sin, yet you obeyed from the heart that form of doctrine to which you were delivered.  And having been set free from sin, you became slaves of righteousness.  I speak in human [terms] because of the weakness of your flesh. For just as you presented your members [as] slaves of uncleanness, and of lawlessness [leading] to [more] lawlessness, so now present your members [as] slaves [of] righteousness for holiness.  For when you were slaves of sin, you were free in regard to righteousness.  What fruit did you have then in the things of which you are now ashamed? For the end of those things [is] death.  But now having been set free from sin, and having become slaves of God, you have your fruit to holiness, and the end, everlasting life.  For the wages of sin [is] death, but the gift of God [is] eternal life in Christ Jesus our Lord.

The following passages explain further on salvation.

> [Rom 5:8 NKJV] But God demonstrates His own love toward us, in that while we were still sinners, Christ died for us.
>
> [Rom 10:9-13 NKJV] ... that if you confess with your mouth the Lord Jesus and believe in your heart that God has raised Him from the dead, you will be saved.  For with the heart one believes unto righteousness, and with the mouth confession is made unto salvation.  For the Scripture says, "Whoever believes on Him will not be put to shame." For there is no distinction between Jew and Greek, for the same Lord over all is rich to all who call upon Him.  For "whoever calls on the name of the LORD shall be saved."
>
> [Jhn 3:16-18 NKJV]  "For God so loved the world that He gave His only begotten Son, that whoever believes in Him should not perish but have everlasting life.  "For God did not send His Son into the world to condemn the world, but that the world through Him might be saved.  "He who believes in Him is not condemned; but he who does not believe is condemned already, because he has not believed in the name of the only begotten Son of God.
>
> [Eph 2:8-9 NKJV] For by grace you have been saved through faith, and that not of yourselves; [it is] the gift of God, not of works, lest anyone should boast.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, Jesus resurrection means anyone who dies will resurrect to an 'everlasting life'. All those who were made to resurrect before(Eg: Lazarus) died later, while Jesus ascended to the skies from infront of His disciples.
This resurrection also means He has achieved victory over death, so that we too have a way to have victory over death by believing in Him.

Comment: Hi and welcome, I've noticed you posted several answers in quick succession that were all quite short and relatively low quality. Please be mindful that we are looking for thorough, well researched answers that would be more comfortable turned in as short essays in a classroom than the typical off the cuff forum type responses. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hope initiating from the resurrection of Jesus Christ presupposes Jesus is the son of God and His sacrifice extends His righteousness to all that believe.
Hope is an expectance; Christian-hope is built on the foundation of Jesus Christ’s work of redemption, which culminated in His victory over sin (the resurrection).

> Romans 5:12-21 Wherefore, as by one man (Adam) sin entered into the world, and death by sin; and so death passed upon all men, for that all have sinned…that as sin hath reigned unto death, even so might grace reign through righteousness unto eternal life by Jesus Christ our Lord
>
> Romans 6:23 for the wages of sin is death; but the gift of God is eternal life through Jesus Christ our Lord.

The hope of Christ accompanies the believer in this life for the life to come.

Answer (score 1):

The resurrection of Jesus Christ follows the plan of redemption which allows for our salvation. Our salvation prepares us for the kingdom of God, and for our work here on earth.

1 Corinthians 15;20-23

20 But now is Christ risen from the dead, and become the firstfruits of them that slept.
21 For since by man came death, by man came also the resurrection of the dead.
22 For as in Adam all die, even so in Christ shall all be made alive.
23 But every man in his own order: Christ the firstfruits; afterward they that are  Christ's at his coming.

```
   Why the resurrection?  To further fulfill the plan of redemption;

      1. The incarnation of the Son of God.
      2. The birth of Jesus Christ.
      3. The life of Jesus Christ.
      4. The Ministry of Jesus Christ.
      5. The death of Jesus Christ.
      6. The Resurrection of Jesus Christ.
      7. The second coming of Jesus Christ


   Does this hope pertain to an individuals every day life experience here on earth?


      Salvation is open to all who believe.
```

Jonn 3;16 For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.

```
      Those who believe and are born again;
```

John 3;5 Jesus answered, Verily, verily, I say unto thee, Except a man be born of water, and of the Spirit, he cannot see the kingdom of God.

```
      Those who walk in the newest of life (born again) are renewing their character 
      day by day to prepare for the kingdom of God and to tell others the gospel.

      Is it a more spiritual hope in Jesus and heaven?

       Our hope is believing in the promises of Jesus Christ.
```